# What are those boxes on the uniforms in TMP?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-uniforms, star-trek-the-motion-picture

I was watching *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* yesterday and saw their uniforms (below): you will note there is a box of some description they wear around their waists.  I was just wondering *what is this box's purpose*?

[image: Uniform with freehand circle]

Comment: This is in great need of some [Freehand Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/252593).

Comment: @Mooz freehand circled ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%28mid_2270s%29) on this particular uniform, that little black box they wear is:

> a life support monitor belt buckle (non-canonically named the perscan device)

Out of canon, we learn more about the [Perscan device](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Perscan)

> The perscan (or perscan device) was **a medical device** used by Starfleet
>   in the 23rd century. **It was a tiny scanner-transceiver which monitored
>   the body's vital signs and transmitted the results to sickbay at all
>   times, providing them with continuous updates on their physical
>   status**. In the uniforms introduced in the 2270s, the perscan was part
>   of the belt ornament. (TOS novelization: Star Trek: The Motion
>   Picture)

This fits in with McCoy's remark early in the film about the sickbay looking more like a computer lab than a medical facility.